# np.savetxt tuple converted into array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, wave

I am trying to pull out a .wav file into a txt file for analysis but I am getting a single value in Audio.txt in the end instead of the all the data points(value). I unable to figure out where I am going wrong in the piece of code given below:

```
import wave, struct
import numpy as np
waveFile = wave.open('test1.wav', 'r')
length = waveFile.getnframes()
for i in range(0,length):
    waveData = waveFile.readframes(1)
    data = struct.unpack("<h", waveData)
    data_x = np.array(int(data[0])) #saving all value in a single array
    #print(int(data[0]))
np.savetxt("Audio.txt", data_x.reshape(1,),delimiter=",")
```

Any help ??

Thank You.

Comment: Show some of the problem output. What is `data_x` like before saving?

Comment: If `data_x.reshape(1,)` does not throw an error this is a strong indication that `data_x` only contains a single value. Since it is overwritten in each loop iteration I'd say you only store the last frame, which probably contains only a single sample.